# Deployment Into Production - Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I've scheduleable Apex classes that call 15 batch classes.  Each one of the batch class will be executed in series, one right after another scheduled at 20 secs apart.

During my unit test, code coverage is >95% on all classes.  But when I clicked "validate deployment" I get the following errors:
1) Problem: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation
2) Invalid type: batch_nameAccount

All of the batch, scheduleable classes as well as the main test class are deployed together.

Why am I getting these errors now?  What do these mean?  Any suggestions to resolve this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In production, click Your Name ->Setup->Develop->Apex Classes then click on the Compile All Classes" link. What errors does it give you?

Comment: @Eric, do you mean Run all Test Classes?

Comment: If I run all tests in Sandbox, all my test classes passed but there are some tests methods from our 3rd party apps that failed.

Comment: Thats not what I stated to do. My comment above was pretty clear on what to do. When you post the error that it says then either it will be clear to you what is wrong or we can help you more effectivly

Comment: Ok, my bad. I didn't see that link.

Comment: @Eric, they all compile successfully in Sandbox and Production.

Comment: interesting. do you have some dynamic reference to a class in the batch_nameAccount that is not being deployed? how are you deploying? ui or ant or something else? any destructive changes? maybe you can post your batch_nameAccount class?

Comment: @Eric, I just spent the last 2 hours breaking my test codes apart.  I put each of the test plan for each batch class and schedule class into their own test method within my test class.  It seams to be working and was successful deployed into production.

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367493/how-to-find-dependent-components-for-a-class-page-trigger-using-api-tooling-or) Hope this link help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367493/how-to-find-dependent-components-for-a-class-page-trigger-using-api-tooling-or